# Why does fallback locale acting like default locale in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, localization, default, multilingual

Consider these two lines in config/app.php :

```
'locale' => 'de',

'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

Why laravel is setting 'en' locale when 'de' exists ?

Comment: cache? try with "php artisan cache:clear" or delete all the files inside the bootstrap/cache folder

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia what do you mean?

Comment: That laravel il caching the config, please try what I have said

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I tried it. Didn't work.